# Custom Classes and Collection Classes

Tags: vb.net, oop, dictionary, inheritance, collections

I have some custom classes and collection classes for those classes. I'm kind of new to actually implementing all of this, and I see a lot of different options but all with their own pros and cons, and I'm having trouble determining the best/right way to do what I need.

For example, I have a Product class with ID and Description properties. I have a ProductCollection class that I basically want to be a dictionary consisting of Product objects. This is a dictionary because there is a performance gain in accessing by key value, which is how I'll reference the objects. The key is Product.ID, and the value is Product.

I'd like to be able to do something like ProductCollection.Add(Product), and the collection will handle signing the dictionary key from the object's ID property. How do I best accomplish this? Implement Dictionary(Of Integer, Product) and override basically all methods to pass in the object and property separately? Or is there a better way?

Also, to give a little more background information to help clarify usage of these classes, there will be a "master" instance of ProductCollection containing all possible products. A ShipTo class will also have a ProductCollection containing specific products that are applicable for that particular ShipTo. My question was specific to the Product/ProductCollection classes, but also applied to the ShipTo classes.

Comment: There is a difference between a collection and a collection class.  The latter will either inherit from a collection (like `Collection(of T)`) to add functionality you need or encapsulate certain aspects.  Otherwise the Q is a bit broad

Comment: You should be inheriting the `KeyedCollection` class:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Plutonix: sorry, I was referring to a collection class, I'll update the question to clarify. That being said, I thought my question was pretty specific.

Comment: jmcilhinney: thanks, that looks like it's exactly what I needed. I overlooked it when comparing it to Dictionary because the "benefit" of a KeyedCollection was it keeps items in the same order that they're added to the collection, at the expense of performance. Since this was not a benefit I was looking for, I kept looking for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would hold a collection of products. I have a `Product` class and a `Products` collection class.

First create the `Product` class which holds all the properties:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Public Class Product
Public Key As String

   Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer,
                  ByVal description As String)

      _id = id
      _description = description

   End Sub

   Private _id As Integer
   Public ReadOnly Property ID() As Integer
      Get
          Return _id
      End Get

   End Property

   Private _description As String
   Public ReadOnly Property Description() As String
      Get
          Return _description
      End Get
   End Property

End Class
```

The create a `Products` collection class to hold the `Product` class:

```
Public Class Products
Inherits KeyedCollection(Of String, Product)

   Protected Overrides Function GetKeyForItem(ByVal item As Product) As String
       Return item.Key
   End Function

End Class
```

You would then use these like this:

```
Dim myProducts As New Products
myProducts.Add(New Product(1,"Table"))
```